# Print parts of a web-page's source in Golang like PHP

Tags: go, web-frameworks

I'm trying to generate a web page in Go lang. I'm currently using the Goji framework ( http://goji.io ) and I want to generate all of the heads and parts of the body of the web-page, but then I want some of the content to be written based on results from the code.

For example as in PHP, one can write HTML, js, or CSS and then in the PHP tags, write the code which is interpreted there.

How can I write my html, css, and js and then have Golang code within it that is complied and executed as the page is rendered?

Comment: Have a look at packages `net/http` and `text/template`. Or maybe use it as a CGI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [issue 13](https://github.com/zenazn/goji/issues/13), use Go [html/template](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package.

i.e.

```
// Shorthand
type M map[string]interface{}

func viewHandler(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    title := c.URLParams["title"]
    p, err := loadPage(title)
    if err != nil {
        ...
    }
    // do other things

    template.ExecuteTemplate(w, "results.html", M{
            "title": title,
            "results": results,
            "pagination": true,
         }
    }
```

> `results.html`

```
{{range .Results }}
   <h1>{{ Result.Name }}</h1>
   <p>{{ Result.Body }}</p>
 {{ end }}
```

---

Using a template is also recommended in [`zenazn/goji/example/main.go`](https://github.com/zenazn/goji/blob/17b9035bcd162f59e1a1247d4a755124c37052c5/example/main.go#L69-L76).

[elithrar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556573/elithrar) also references [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404825/print-parts-of-a-web-pages-source-in-golang-like-php/25404928?noredirect=1#comment39626439_25404928) the "[**Writing Web Applications** article, section **The html/template package**](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_6)" for more.

Comment: Also see http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_6 - which is a ground up example. The one in that Goji issue isn't runnable, but just demonstrates the "how" of rendering a template.

Comment: @elithrar good point. I have referenced the article in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: what is meant by the Goji was isn't runnable? Why not?

Comment: @user3743069 The *code* linked to in [the Goji issue](https://github.com/zenazn/goji/issues/13) is a not a fully working application because it was targeted to a specific question - i.e. the purpose was to help one user only. Or in other words: if you copy+paste it, it won't run. This is not the same thing as the [Goji example](https://github.com/zenazn/goji/blob/17b9035bcd162f59e1a1247d4a755124c37052c5/example/main.go#L69-L76), which is fully functional.